# kafka connect: config file not found

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to kafka and learning to use kafka connect to read from a text (.txt) file.
I created the source-config file and worker config files and saved them as .properties files under resources.
 
I am getting a NoSuchFileException for both the config files when i run the following from terminal:
`/bin/connect-standalone.sh my-standalone.properties my-file-source.properties`

```
#my-file-source.properties config file
name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=/tmp/my-test.txt
topic=my-connect-test
```

```
# my-standalone.properties worker config file
 
#bootstrap kafka servers
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
 
# specify input data format
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
 
# The internal converter used for offsets, most will always want to use the built-in default
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
 
# local file storing offsets and config data
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

Is adding config files to resources the right way? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please provide location of your properties files.

Comment: Why not provide the full path instead of the relative one?